# variable was not declared in this scope gcc error

Tags: c++, gcc

I have the following templated function

```
//This is a very naive implementation, but it will do
template<class T>
T determinant(const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &matrix)
{
    sci::assertThrow(square(matrix), sci::err());
    if (matrix.size() == 1)
        return matrix[0][0];
    else if (matrix.size() == 2)
        return matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1] - matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0];
    else
    {
        double result = 0;
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> minor(matrix.size() - 1);
        double multiplier = 1.0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < minor.size(); ++j)
            {
                if (j < i)
                    minor[j] = matrix[j];
                else
                    minor[j] = matrix[j + 1];
            }
            result += multiplier * matrix[0][i] * sci::determinant(minor);
            multiplier *= -1.0;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

which compiled fine with visual studio 2015, however gcc says

```
g++ -c -Wall -g -std=c++11 -fPIC -o3 -o build/svector.o svector/svector.cpp
In file included from svector/svector_internal.h:6:0,
                 from svector/svector.cpp:1:
svector/../include/svector/dep/svector.h: In function 'T sci::determinant(const std::vector<std::vector<T> >&)':
svector/../include/svector/dep/svector.h:2888:28: error: 'minor' was not declared in this scope
     for (size_t j = 0; j < minor.size(); ++j)
                            ^
svector/../include/svector/dep/svector.h:2895:60: error: 'minor' was not declared in this scope
     result += multiplier * matrix[0][i] * sci::determinant(minor);
                                                            ^
```

It looks to me like minor is definitely in scope at the point that gcc is complaining about. Can anyone shed any light on the reason for this error?

Comment: Could it be you missed to `#include <vector>`? It's often the case that some standard library implementations automatically include other standard header files, while different implementations do not. If that doesn't answer your question provide a [MCVE] please, that everyone can reproduce.

Comment: You're going to need to post your [MCVE]. And I'm really getting tired of having to say that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sys/sysmacros.h` in Glibc contains the macro definitions:

```
# define major(dev) gnu_dev_major (dev)
# define minor(dev) gnu_dev_minor (dev)
```

This is probably being included through some system header which you are including.

The parentheses after `minor` in the variable definition cause the macro invocation, which changes the variable name. The other uses of `minor` have no parentheses and therefore the macro isn't invoked, which causes `minor` to reference a nonexistent variable.

You can either rename the `minor` variable or undefine `minor` to fix the error.